# What is the difference between "to stop", "to halt" and "to cease"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

What is the difference between "to stop", "to halt" and "to cease"? These three verbs are translated into russian in the same way, but I feel that they are not interchangeble.

Comment: Please look them up in a monolingual dictionary. Thanks. Then, ask a question.

Comment: _Halt_ means _stop moving. Cease_ means _stop doing something. Stop_ is a more general term that can include both meanings.

Answer (score 1):

*Halt* means stop moving. *Cease* means stop doing something. *Stop* is a more general term that can include both meanings. –
Kate Bunting